# I can not slice the data for a unique date

Tags: python, indexing, slice, analysis, finance

I have been running a series of codes, and they all seem to be working really well, until I come to the last step. Here are the few codes that I ran:

```
rds = pd.read_csv('RDS-A.csv')
print(rds.head())
print(rds.shape)
print(rds.describe())
rds_2015 = rds.loc['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']
print(rds_2015.loc['2015-01-30'])
```

Error

> KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) get_loc(self, key, method,
>   tolerance) 2896 try: -> 2897 return self._engine.get_loc(key) 2898
>   except KeyError: pandas/_libs/index.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc() pandas/_libs/index.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc() KeyError: '2015-01-30'

Comment: apparently there is not data with index '2015-01-30' but we cant help you if you dont give further information like input data

Comment: like i said. we cant help you if you dont give us some data to look at

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVTCGqYfheY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I got the data from yahoo finance from 01-01-2008 to 31-12-2018 for RDS-A ticker

Comment: `rds_2015 = rds.loc['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']` returns an empty dataframe. of corse you get an error in the next line. see my answer, which might help you

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Comments may or may not be shown initially, and in any order. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
rds = pd.read_csv('RDS-A.csv')
rds['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(rds['Date'])
rds.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
rds_2015 = rds['2015']
```

If you want to slice the data by date you have to have a `datetime` format. And for simplicity you can set that column as index. Then you can easily do sth like `rds['2015']` to get all 2015 values

Comment: luigigi I LOVE YOU. Something that I had been trying for 15 hours you solved it. Thank you so much

Comment: glad it helped. it would be nice if you accept the answer